# Automatic vhost folders in apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I've currently got the following in my vhost config which is working, however I'd like to modify it.

Currently my vhost config looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName dev
    ServerAlias *.dev

    CustomLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
    ErrorLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/owen/Sites/%-2+/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

So this automatically routes, urls like `http://owen.website.dev` to `/Users/owen/Sites/owen.website/`

However, I'd like to modify it so the `owen` prefix is automated, for example, when you visit `http://owen.website.dev` it goes to `/Users/owen/Sites/website/`

I tried simply doing

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName dev
    ServerAlias *.dev

    CustomLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
    ErrorLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/owen/Sites/owen.%-2+/httpdocs
    and
    #VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/owen/Sites/owen\.%-2+/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

However no avail, could somebody please provide me with the correct `VirtuaDocumentroot` to enable this automated vhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error and decyphering the apache doc, I found it was as simple as removing the `- and +` from the path.

So if you use

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName dev
    ServerAlias *.dev

    CustomLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-access_log" combinedmassvhost
    ErrorLog "/Users/owen/Sites/logs/dev-error_log"

    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/owen/Sites/%2/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

The way this works I believe (more than likely wrong) if you imagine you have a URL looking like

`environment.project.dev` - apache explodes via the `.` giving you

```
$0 = environment.project.dev
$1 = environment
$2 = project
$3 = dev
```

as `project` is the folder you want to load, you just need to reference the `$2` variable, leaving me with

```
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/owen/Sites/%2/httpdocs
```

this would load in the above example `/Users/owen/Sites/project/httpdocs`

One of the benefits of this is allows you to have for example in your hostfile or DNS level

```
192.168.1.50    matt.project.dev 
192.168.1.51    emily.project.dev
192.168.1.52    shaun.project.dev
```

then you can view everybody else's version of the site easily.